# Randomizing responses from jquery typer

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify this code to output randomized responses, the code selects one response from section one, a response from section 2, and a response from section 3.

https://github.com/yckart/jquery.typer.js

```
(function($){
$.fn.typer = function(text, options){
    options = $.extend({}, {
        char: '',
        delay: 5000,
        duration: 800,
        endless: true,
        onType: $.noop,
        afterAll: $.noop,
        afterPhrase: $.noop
    }, options || text);

    text = $.isPlainObject(text) ? options.text : text;
    text = $.isArray(text) ? text : text.split(" ");

    return this.each(function(){
        var elem = $(this),
            isVal = {input:1, textarea:1}[this.tagName.toLowerCase()],
            isTag = false,
            timer,
            c = 0;

        (function typetext(i) {
            var e = ({string:1, number:1}[typeof text] ? text : text[i]) + '',
                char = e.substr(c++, 1);

            if( char === '<' ){ isTag = true; }
            if( char === '>' ){ isTag = false; }
            elem[isVal ? "val" : "html"](e.substr(0, c) + ($.isFunction(options.char) ? options.char() : options.char || ' '));
            if(c <= e.length){
                if( isTag ){
                    typetext(i);
                } else {
                    timer = setTimeout(typetext, options.duration/10, i);
                }
                options.onType(timer);
            } else {
                c = 0;
                i++;

                if (i === text.length && !options.endless) {
                    return;
                } else if (i === text.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                timer = setTimeout(typetext, options.delay, i);
                if(i === text.length - 1) options.afterAll(timer);
                options.afterPhrase(timer);
            }
        })(0);
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

the responses code is as follows

```
    if (animation) {

  var text = $('#home .typer-title'),
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textOne = "response",
      textTwo = "response",
      textTwo = "response",
      textTwo = "response",
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      textThree = "response";
      if (!!$.prototype.typer) {
        text.typer([textOne,textTwo,textThree]);
      }
}
```

I do apologize my java-script isn't up to snuff helpful hints or code snippets would be appreciative in making this change

Comment: Do you mean randomized predefined responses? or random text responses?

Comment: Random predefined responses preferably it grabs one from textone, then grabs one from text two and the one from textthree, then repeats back and grabs another random text one ect..